# Highcharts: Stacked area tooltip showing wrong value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using area chart in highcharts. I need stacked area chart and tooltip must not be shared.

Please refer fiddle here:
jsfiddle.net/xqk6etzd/

Problem is:
When I hover mouse on S2 (after all dots of S1 are 0), it shows S1 value in tooltip instead of S2. 
You can try to hide S3 for better testing.

Again, tooltip mustn't be shared, so I set shared:false in tooltip option.

Is there any such bug like this in highcharts? Or some problem in my code?

Please help.

Comment: Well, you have exactly two the same stacked points in the same place. Highcharts searches for points using distance between point marker and mouse pointer. When two points are exactly in the same place, then the first one is used in the tooltip only (and S1 is first series in the array). That's why shared tooltip is the solution in that kind of charts. Just out of the curiosity: why you can't use  `shared`?

Comment: The reason behind not using shared is, there will be more than 24 series in chart and shared tooltip will show 24 series values which will look crowded. Anyway, I know what you wanna say and I understand it. I am thinking to adopt some other possible chart. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

stacking is set to normal, that means one area chart is on top of another. The behavior is correct:

```
plotOptions: {
  area: {
    stacking: 'normal'
  },
```

But, if you really need to change it, you can check the value of the actual area, and if it is equal to zero just swap it with the next value (jsfiddle):

```
tooltip: {
  shared: false,
  formatter: function() {
    if (this.y == 0) {
      return this.series.chart.series[1].name + ': ' +this.series.chart.series[1].yData[this.x];
    } else
      return this.series.name + ': ' +this.y;
  }
},
```

Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/39j73xh2/) example:

```
 $(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'area'
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
      formatter: function() {
        if ((this.y == 0)&&(this.series.name==this.series.chart.series[0].name)) {
        debugger;
          return '<b>'+ this.series.chart.series[1].name +'</b>:'  +this.series.chart.series[1].yData[this.x];
        } else
          return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b>:'  +this.y;
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      },
      series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
          events: {
            click: function() {
              alert("column index: " + this.series.columnIndex);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      index: 1,
      "name": "S1",
      "data": [619, 406, 300, 41, 174, 10, 235, 495, 568, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }, {
      index: 2,
      "name": "S2",
      "data": [507, 90, 752, 548, 133, 528, 151, 553, 734, 341, 774, 810, 618, 89, 125, 202, 354, 317, 239, 82, 112, 155, 849, 258, 848]
    }, {
      index: 3,
      "name": "S3",
      "data": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 593, 110, 705, 569, 793, 437, 173, 300, 618, 693, 138, 38, 106, 525, 142, 807]
    }]
  });

});
```